# Should I use links in headings? (HTML)

Tags: html, browser

According to W3Schools.com:
"Headings Are Important
Search engines use the headings to index the structure and content of your web pages.

Users skim your pages by its headings. It is important to use headings to show the document structure.

headings should be used for main headings, followed by  headings, then the less important , and so on."

So if I am making a website about pets would I want my main link bar(Normally the element at the top of every website) to be headings that contain links to the "dog" page, "cat" page, "fish" page, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A heading appears before the body of the section. A menu of items linking to sections is not a collection of headings.

A navigation menu should typically be a `<nav>` element, containing a list (`<ul>` unless the pages are intended to be read in a specific order, in which case `<ol>`), containing list items (`<li>`) with a link (`<a>`) in each.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Comment: I agree with this, but what's the supporting evidence for this, other than anecdotal experience. It'd be nice to see W3C, or Deque, or some web/accessibility authority say what standard practice should be.

Answer (score 1):

Headings as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp should not be used to navigate around a page, and should instead be used as titles of pages.

`li` tags are normally used for making a horizontal list containing `<a>` links to each page:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="dogpagelink">Dogs</a></li>
  <li><a href="catpagelink">Cats</a></li>
  <li><a href="fishpagelink">Fish</a></li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```